# How can I access both of tables'fields in leftJoin in Yii2

Tags: yii2, left-join

I need tour's fields but below code just get tourPackage's fields and I have to use Active Record.

I know I have to use property in another model for fix this problem but I don't want use property because there are a lot of fields or property.

How can I get tour's table data ?

```
$models = TourPackage::find()->select(['tour.*'])->leftJoin('tour', 'tour.id=tour_package.tour_id')->all();
```

Comment: Have you create tour relation in TourPackage model?

Comment: yes. i have this relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using `TourPackage` object ,
so you can't get attributes of Tour model.
If you want to get Tour model attributes,please try `asArray()`

ex.

```
$models = TourPackage::find()->select(['tour.*'])->leftJoin('tour', 'tour.id=tour_package.tour_id')->asArray()->all();
```

Now you will get `Tour`  model attributes.

Comment: It returns integers as strings

Answer (score 1):

In `TourPackage` you need to define public attributes, that you will join from `Tour`.
For instance if you have column number in tour, then you can write:

```
class TourPackage extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $number
    // ..and other properties you take from tour
```

in `TourPackage` class, and add the following select in Query:

```
$models = TourPackage::find()->addSelect(['tour_package.*', 'tour.number AS number'])->leftJoin('tour', 'tour.id=tour_package.tour_id')->all();
```

Of course, you can write `addSelect(['tour_package.*', 'tour.*'])`, but in that case `tour` columns with similar name will override `tour_package` columns.